# javascript: JSON.Stringify not showing the whole object

Tags: javascript

I have a axios request and the err object in catch looks like this

[image]

But when i try to check the err object using

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
```

I see only

```
{
  "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 400\n    at createError (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:43013:15)\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:43247:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42487:7)",
  "config": {
    "url": "dj-rest-auth/login/",
    "method": "post",
    "data": "{\"email\":\"admin@test.com\",\"password\":\"admin\"}",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "baseURL": "http://localhost:8025",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1
  }
}
```

I dont see the reponse object inside the err object

How to make `JSON.stringify` show the whole object

Answer (score 0):

Do not `JSON.stringify()` the error object. Instead just `console.log(err)`

Answer (score -2):

the simplest way to see the whole object is to simply call

`JSON.stringify()`

with no other arguments than the object itself.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: How is this any different to `console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));`?

Comment: This isn't different in any relevant way. It's a very wrong answer.